# 13.04 desktop suddenly disappeared

Tags: desktop-environments

I have seen an answer from version 12 to try

unity --reset

but when I try this, it's deprecated

I was able to run ccsm, but I don't know what to do to get back the bar, and the menu.

Equally important, what did I do to get it to disappear?

It's not just the docking bar.  I have no window borders.  It's like the window manager is broken.  Is there any way for me to manually kill the window manager and run a different one while I am finding out what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

in the ccsm search for unity plugin and enable it.. it should be on top.

Comment: No dice.  It's like the window manager isn't there.  I have no window borders.  This has happened twice. The first time, I reloaded the system since I didn't know how I had corrupted it.